# Google Maps JavaScript API Place Auto-complete Address Form stopped Working

Tags: google-maps-api-3

So currently I've almost finished my website just testing for bugs and I came across a bug on my website to do with Google's JavaScript Auto-Complete Address Form.

The following URL is an example which I used which hasn't been modified:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Currently my version was working for the past 20 days without a problem, but today it suddenly decided "you know what I don't want to work". It provides the following message:
[image]

This error has been happening today but it has been working for the last 20 days and I haven't changed anything in the code or the API key, so I have no idea what the problem is.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Literally it is the standard version which is provided on the Google Developers Website at the URL provided above, the code is as below, :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <style>
      #locationField, #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
      }
      .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
      }
      #address {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f0ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
      }
      #address td {
        font-size: 10pt;
      }
      .field {
        width: 99%;
      }
      .slimField {
        width: 80px;
      }
      .wideField {
        width: 200px;
      }
      #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
             onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>

    <table id="address">
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
              id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
// [END region_geolocation]

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDdvFbc83j3kLRKr4ECIDrXRAt1WBHkSTU&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**
I've just logged into Google Developers and regenerated the API key and copied it all into a blank HTML and I still have the same problem.

Comment: There is a problem with your key.  Are you using a browser key or a server key?   What does **your** code look like, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Ok I have edited the post and it now contains the code with my API key, my one contained no modifications apart from the css

Answer (score 0):

Ok I regenerated the key and plugged it in that didn't work, but then randomly 20 mins later it works.

Anyway thanks for your help :)